# Mysql workbench keep fetching

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL on my laptop to connect to the server. My sql code is as follows.

```
 select flw_1.flw_id, flw_1.screen_name, flw_2.screen_name
 from
 (
    select screen_name, flw_id
    from fyp.twitter_flw
    where user_id=1 ) as flw_1
 join
 (
    select screen_name, flw_id
    from fyp.twitter_flw
    where user_id=2 )  as flw_2

 on flw_1.flw_id=flw_2.flw_id
 where flw_1.screen_name != flw_2.screen_name
```

The code is basically joining two tables that contains over a million rows. At first, mysql workbench console response stays at `Running...`. After changing some server system variables, the query takes 35.768 secs but it keeps `Fetching...` for almost an hour. It looks like this:
[image: Screenshot]

What is the problem? What is mysql doing when it is fetching? Should I set other server system variables? Or it is because of slow network? Could it be possible that it is that database structure is not optimal?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please provide information about your table structures. It probably means that it is downloading a very large quantity of data. Have you tried an EXPLAIN query? You may be generating a result with billions of rows unintentionally.

Comment: Right [Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) may improve the speed.